# How do I prevent my console app from closing until its condition is met?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# 
and this is my program.
I will guess a number between 1 and 3
If my guess is correct, it'll close my console app after I press enter
which is not the problem.
The problem is, if i guessed incorrectly, I will guess again, after I pressed enter program closes. 
What is the solution, to prevent my console app closing when pressing enter after I guessed wrong?
This is the code
Sorry about my question..

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 3);
int num2;
Console.WriteLine("Guess my number");
num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (num2 == num1)
    Console.WriteLine("Very Good!");

else
    Console.WriteLine("Guess again");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Just a small hint to help your program in general - `rnd.Next(1, 3);` returns a number from `1` to `2` inclusive - the `3` is an **exclusive** upper bound.

Comment: Another small hint that will help you a lot with all of your programming code.
ALWAYS try to give variable significant names , even if you are writing a small piece of code. 
For Instance: `int GeneratedRandomNumber= rnd.Next(1, 3);int GuessedNumber =   int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Writing a clean code, is a habit all serious programmers should respect.
@kyriacoss looks correct and answered your question.
Happy coding

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 3);
int num2;

Console.WriteLine("Guess my number");

while(true)
{  
   //NOTE, if the user entered characters other than number, the program
   //will throw an exception, you should check user input before making the parsing
   num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   if (num2 == num1)
   {
   Console.WriteLine("Very Good!");
   break;
   }
   else
    Console.WriteLine("Guess again");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in a do...while statement. So:

```
do 
{
    num2 = int.parse...
    .... 
}
while (num2 != num1);
Console.ReadLine();
```

What this does is it keeps on executing the code in the do while loop **until** num2 is equal to num1, in this case when the user guesses it correctly!